# She said that she has/had seen a tiger

Tags: tense, backshifting

Which one is more correct:

> 1) She said that she **has** seen a tiger.
>   2) She said that she **had** seen a tiger.

Comment: They mean different things.

Comment: If she **has** seen a tiger, you had better take care. If she **had** seen a tiger, you don't need to worry. The are different time frames.

Comment: Both are grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> She *said* that she *had seen* a tiger.

The version **2**) (*Past Simple* + *Past Perfect*) is definitely correct, but it can mean two slightly different things: **a**) she saw that tiger *in a particular situation* some time earlier (e. g. as a part of her story about visiting the zoo) or **b**) she (already) *had an experience* of seeing a tiger (and e. g. for that reason was no more interested in going to the zoo; *Past Perfect* works as 'backshifted' *Present Perfect* here). But how to distinguish between the two senses without an additional context? It is possible for the speaker to emphasize the sense **b**) by using '*has seen*' without backshifting to '*she said*', like in your sentence 1), because she *still has* that experience (it can't be 'undone', so the situation is *still true*), almost like here (*Past Simple* + *Present Simple*):

> She *said* the earth *goes* round the sun.

It's within these rules:

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm

- For a *general truth* [the example above] there is *no need* for
  backshift.
- If a situation is *still true* [your case], backshift
  is *optional*.

So the version **1**) is also correct:

> She *said* that she *has seen* a tiger.

As mentioned in comments, it can also mean that her seeing a tiger happened just before the moment of her speaking, and that could be not just '*still true*' but terribly actual (as in case 'she says she has seen').